# The working copy requires a newer version of Subversion than Xcode supports

Tags: xcode, software-update

I just installed `Xcode 4.6` (I had `Xcode 4.5.1`). I just opened an existing project and got this message:

> The working copy "path/to/my project" requires a newer version of Subversion than Xcode supports.

I am currently using *Cornerstone* for svn, and understand that I can probably ignore this message - but since I want to be up-to-date, what do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is about development tools and is Off Topic here this should be migrated to Stack Overflow

Comment: I'll leave this open. We welcome user level questions about Xcode, shell scripting and open source tools like SVN. If the OP wants it migrated we can assist, but "programming" means code level questions as opposed to tools programmers use on OS X or iOS. As always, [meta] is the place for Q&A on what's on or off-topic.